# How to tell CMake which Python version to use in manylinux?

Tags: python, docker, cmake, python-manylinux

I want to build my code in a manylinux docker container (quay.io/pypa/manylinux1_i686). Inside manylinux I would like to use Python 3.7. This is why in my `CMakeLists.txt` I got the following line:

```
find_package(Python REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter Development NumPy)
```

I get the error message:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find Python (missing: Python_INCLUDE_DIR Development NumPy)
  (found version "2.4.3")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPython.cmake:194 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:32 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

How do I tell the `find_package` function, where my Python is stored and which Python I want to use? I can find my desired Python executable in `/opt/python/cp37-cp37m/bin/python3.7`.